# How to redirect only sites with specific domain name?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect all sites that as a specific word to one site.
I try to explain myself better.

I have a domain, it's example name is example.com
What I need is when an user digit: 
something.example.com
or
anothertext.example.com 
or 
blablabla.example.com 
and many others it will be redirect to example.com

I found this code:

```py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

But it redirect all my domains in that server.
I discover it because I create a new virtual host, with a new domain but I can't see it on the web because it automatically redirects on example.com

So, I thought that maybe if I specify the word: "example" I can solve the problem.

Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks for help.

Luca.

Answer (score 0):

Check one of rules that you more prefer:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # something.example.com/any to https://example.com/
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^something\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/ [R=301,L]

    # something.example.com/any to https://example.com/any
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^something\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # something.example.com/any to https://example.com/, full subdomain with and without www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?something\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/ [R=301,L]

    # something.example.com/any to https://example.com/any, full subdomain with and without www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?something\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```